# Registrar alterações no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Preciso **registrar todas as alterações no banco de dados**, como `UPDATE`, `INSERT` e etc, de forma que eu possa **restaurar o último backup** e **executar as queries à partir do último backup**, excluindo manualmente as queries indesejadas.

Li sobre o *Log binário do MySQL*, mas é possível **excluir as queries indesejadas** e abrir o arquivo do log de forma amigável para a edição?

Preciso de algo semelhante a isso:

```
-- [...]
-- 2017-04-11 22:07:32
UPDATE foo SET bar = 'fubá';
-- 2017-04-11 22:08:07
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id = 127;
-- [...]
```

Uso *MySQL 5.7.14* no *Windows*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia,

*Preciso registrar todas as alterações no banco de dados, como UPDATE, INSERT e etc* » Sugiro você fazer isso por conta própria, crie uma tabela `log` ou similar com as informações desejadas, como data e hora, descrição, operação realizada e qual foi usuário. Eu faço isso há vários anos e os logs já me salvaram de situações típicas como "sumiu o cliente X..."

Agora, *de forma que eu possa restaurar o último backup e executar as queries à partir do último backup* me parece bem mais complicado. Sugiro você agendar dumps de backup de hora em hora, ou na frequencia ideal, e ter estes dumps como opção de restore.

*mas é possível excluir as queries indesejadas e abrir o arquivo do log de forma amigável para a edição?* » posso estar enganado, mas lendo assim me parece uma solução "mágica demais" para resolver uma situação bem complexa. Eu tentaria com os dumps de backup e, se necessário, ter as queries na tabela de log e executa-las numa rotina de manutenção. Mas novamente, eu implementaria isso via programação, por exemplo em PHP.

Considero potencialmente perigoso ficar editando manualmente SQLs de backup antes de fazer um restore, procuro evitar este tipo de abordagem.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Então, @FernandoMertins, Imagine que eu tenha feito um backup às 10h. Após isso já foram executadas várias queries e uma dessas queries é indesejada. Suponha que eu restaure o backup das 10h e re-execute todas as queries, exceto a que não quero. Se eu fizer um log na forma de texto, contendo todas as queries, a aplicação perde MUITO desempenho. Se eu programar um dump de x em x tempo, vai me custar muito espaço em disco, uma vez que vou ter dados praticamente idênticos repetidas vezes.

Comment: Bom dia, concordo. Lendo a tua explicação e tentando imaginar o cenário, por exemplo _tenha feito um backup às 10h. Após isso já foram executadas várias queries e uma dessas queries é indesejada._ me parece que você está tentando resolver a consequencia (a query indesejada) de uma forma inadequada, com backups. Talvez mudar a abordagem e garantir o máximo possível que a query indesejada não chegue a ser executada... :-) Ideia, usar uma transação, pedir mais uma confirmação ao usuário antes de confirmar a instrução SQL, este tipo de coisa. Abraços!